# Lose changes on shutdown Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

Microsoft replaced Virtual PC with Hyper-V for Windows 8. In Virtual PC I was able to shutdown the instance and lose changes form that session. This is important for testing that I can restart the VM in the original state.

When I perform either a shutdown or turnoff the VM in Hyper-V it saves the changes made while running.  How do I setup a VM in Hyper-V to lose the changes on shutdown?

Comment: Does the Automatic Stop Action guest setting govern a user initiated shut down of the guest or does it only govern a shut down of the Hyper-V host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, do it different.

Ignrore shutdown. Use a snapshot to snapshot the known good state, then roll back. THis way you can also test thigns like installs and restart during them.

Comment: +1 Snapshots, all other hypervisors work this same way too.

Comment: More work than the Virtual PC option to just close and discard changes. Oh well, I a few extra steps.

Comment: @Josh You're also getting a vastly more powerful and flexible hypervisor than Virtual PC. Stop yer whinin'.  :P